# Get 3D coordinates of an object after rotation around arbitrary point ( car steering simulation )

Tags: opengl, rotation

I managed to develop a basic car simulation in OpenGL using keyboard events for the movement of the car. The problem I am having trouble with is getting the position of my car after I am steering it to the left or the right. I am doing this using glTranslatef() glRotatef() glTranslatef() model for rotating my car around a point on the Y axis so that the car is moving only in the XZ plane.

The renderScene function summarized :

```
 void renderScene( void ) {

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(cameraX,cameraY,cameraZ,lookAtX,0,lookAtZ,upX, upY, upZ);


  glPushMatrix();

    if (steerLeft){
        glTranslatef(xTemp,0,zTemp+R); 
        glRotatef(angle,0,1,0);
        glTranslatef(-xTemp,0,-zTemp-R);    
    }
    else 
          if (steerRight){  
            glTranslatef(-xTemp,0,-zTemp-R);
            glRotatef(angle,0,1,0);
            glTranslatef(xTemp,0,zTemp+R);
          }
          else{ 
            glRotatef(angle,0,1,0); 
            glTranslatef(x1,0,z1);
        }
    glutWireCube(1,1,1);  

  glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

where x1 is incremented/decremented accordingly after pressing W,S keys and when I am pressing W+A or W+D for example the angle is changed accordingly so that the rotation behaves as expected (worth to mention that I am dealing with a sequence of transformations not just a single Translate->Rotate->Translate ).

As far as R goes it will be the radius of the circle the object would form if it were to go 360 in one direction around that point. The xTemp and zTemp variables keep the objects position right before the steering is made.

I searched for answers to this issue and found some suggestions that I should use : `glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, m)` function to store the current matrix and get the x,z coordinates of the object after the transformations using m[12], m[14], but I was not able to make it work.

I am quite sure that I am missing something simple here because OpenGL already is making those computations for me, to set the object`s position on the screen and all I would need would be the "last computation", meaning the final position of my object after it was rotated incrementally multiple times.

Comment: try to read a bit on `Model Matrix` && `projection Matrix`. Try also the `Matrix Stack` (depreciated now) operations.

Comment: I am confused how this is going to help me, I am looking for some method to retrieve coordinates of an object after it is rotated around a specific point.